# SUM() of TIME column on google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this table:

[image: Big query table]

The TripDrivingDuration column is a String type column, I tried to cast the string to time then make the sum but doesn't work.

[image: Failed attempt]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What are you expecting the results to be? It doesn't make sense to sum timestamps.

Comment: Hi Elliott,

The column means the duration of a trip so I want to get the total duration for ever deviceId grouped by Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
WITH DATA as(
select 29 as VehicleId, '2017-01-02T 15:57:063000' as TripDateTime, '00:00:28' as TripDrivingDuration union all
select 29 as VehicleId, '2017-01-02T 13:23:12' as TripDateTime, '00:00:21' as TripDrivingDuration union all
select 29 as VehicleId, '2017-01-02T 17:23:05.063000' as TripDateTime, '00:07:11.9370000' as TripDrivingDuration union all
select 29 as VehicleId, '2017-01-02T 14:59:44.063000' as TripDateTime, '00:08:19.9370000' as TripDrivingDuration union all
select 29 as VehicleId, '2017-01-02T 15:45:44.063000' as TripDateTime, '00:01:22.9370000' as TripDrivingDuration union all
select 29 as VehicleId, '2017-01-02T 15:17:58.063000' as TripDateTime, '00:03:29.9370000' as TripDrivingDuration union all
select 29 as VehicleId, '2017-01-02T 18:52:15' as TripDateTime, '00:01:26' as TripDrivingDuration union all
select 29 as VehicleId, '2017-01-02T 17:05:24.063000' as TripDateTime, '00:13:09.9370000' as TripDrivingDuration
)

SELECT
  VehicleId,
  SUM(UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%H:%M:%S', REGEXP_EXTRACT(TripDrivingDuration, r'(.*)\.\d+')))) elapsed_time
FROM data
GROUP BY VehicleId
```

Comment: Thank you so much Will this help me a lot. this is the answer